# Outlook Issue when trying to access from Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, com, outlook

Actually,I'm trying to access `Outlook` `Distribution Lists`.
Everything Works fine in my local PC when I try to run it with `Visual Studio`.
But,When I `host` my Application on `Windows Server 2012` and try to run with the `domain`,I'm getting an `error`.
I'm using `Outlook 2007`.
I have Installed `64 bit` version of `MS Office 2013` in my `Windows Server` of 64 bit.

My code is as follows :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application OApplicaiton = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();   
var outlook = new Application().GetNamespace("MAPI");
var folder1 = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
foreach (var curr in folder1.Items.OfType<DistListItem>())
{
  Cmb_GlobalLists.Items.Add(curr.DLName);
}
```

and My `error` is :

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

can anyone help me ?
Is there any thing to do with PIA's?

Comment: If I had a dollar for everytime I recommended [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757), I'd be rich!

Answer (score 2):

CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE is most likely raised if your app and Outlook are running in different security contexts. Is either app running with elevated privileges (Run As Administrator)?

Comment: actually,I can run perfectly,when i try to run my application.but,when hosted on server,I can't access the lists.
Now,I tried opening Outlook as "Run as Administrator".
but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I did  not suggest running your code as an admin, I just pointed out that you get that error if the security contexts are different. How and why they are different is a different question. Do you start both your app and Outlook from Windows Explorer?

Comment: thanks for your help..But I'm unable to get exactly what you are saying.can you explain it clearly(if you don't mind).
Actually,I'm new to programming :(

Comment: Does it work if you start Outlook (make sure it is closed first) from Windows Explorer and then starting your app also from Windows Explorer?

Comment: yeah..I have done all those..but its not working...I think it might be problem with the COM dll or IIS Settings..
Can you suggest me the settings that I need to set in server for accessing in local PC?

Comment: IIS settings? Are you running this from a web server?

Comment: This has nothing to do with IIS setting but with the fact that you are running Outlook from a service. You cannot do that.

Comment: and one last question...
actually,I am trying to access lists of clients from outlook on my website?
does the browser give permission to access outlook lists from client PC on our website?

Comment: You cannot access client's Outlook from the server. You can use EWS etc. to talk to the user's Exchange server. On the client side, you can create an instance of the Outlook.Application COM object if the browser (IE only) will allow you.

Comment: is there any link which provides a solution for that?
because I'm cracking my head from the past 1 week :(

Comment: You can directly access the Active Directory. You can also use CDO 1.21 (deprecated) or Redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/). Are you trying to access DLs residing on an Exchange server?

Answer (score 0):

Start Internet Information Services (IIS).
Right-click your application's virtual directory, and then click Properties.
Click the Directory Security tab. Under Anonymous access and authentication control, click Edit.
Make sure the Anonymous access check box is not selected and that Integrated Windows authentication is the only selected check box.
Configure ASP.NET to use Windows authentication with impersonation, use the following configuration in WebConfig.
...
authentication mode="Windows"/> 
identity impersonate="true"/>
...